# Getting address detail from marker using Google Maps for ExpressionEngine

Tags: add-on, google-maps-for-ee

I have a Google Map generated from multiple entries and using Google Maps for ExpressionEngine.

Each entry can have multiple markers. Basically, each entry is an business with multiple locations. For logistical regions it is not practical to create a separate entry for each location.

My question is how can I get the address info from each marker to output on my template. I can do it if there is only a single marker per entry by using the built in function to copy the formatted address to another field but since I have many markers in an entry this won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try the `parse` parameter. This will allow you to loop through the JSON data of each marker and output the formatted address as needed.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue and I will look a little deeper.

https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/fieldtype#parse

Comment: That's actually looking pretty good. Thank you. Though I did find that adding the parse parameter broke the tag pair for some reason. Just adding a field to hold the json data then using {marker:formatted_address} seems to do the job though. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting about that tagpair breaking. I have not seen it break on my end, and should work reliably. In any case, glad you got it working.